# Cannot get my post-commit script to run (git)

Tags: git, hook

I want my remote git-repo to create a zip file from one folder in the master branch every time someone pushes.

I renamed the post-commit.sample file and added the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "creating zip"
/usr/local/bin/git archive --format=zip --output=~/the-folder.zip master:the-folder
echo "creating zip done"
```

When I commit from my client I don't see the echoes and I don't get any zip-file. The post-commit file has execution privileges.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the remote repository you should use the `post-recieve` hook. I think the `post-commit` hook is only run on the clients, and not on the remote repository.

From the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

> **post-receive**
>
> This hook is invoked by git-receive-pack on the remote repository,
>   which happens when a git push is done on a local repository. It
>   executes on the remote repository once after all the refs have been
>   updated.