# Git Post-Commit Hook

Tags: git, rsync, post-commit-hook

Git newbie here. 
I want a post commit hook that when run will copy the latest code from the repository to a different server in a new folder. The folder name should be what I wrote in the git commit comment.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you realize that a post-commit hook will run client side? It's more common to do that in post-receive, so that when you push something to the repo, it updates another location too

Comment: no i didnt. still getting my head around git.

so i need a post-receive hook?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999354/cannot-get-my-post-commit-script-to-run-git

Comment: I don't think it's a dup, because OP wants to create a hook, and the linked question is about a script not running, ie. not the same thing

Comment: I dont think that is what im after. but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't look so certain as to which hook you need, according to the coments, I'm posting an answer based on post-receive hook. This is a server-side hook that will ran after everything is received in the server, after a push. A post-commit hook would be client-side, and would run after every commit (for more info about git hooks, see https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Assuming a bash script, you can use:

```
MESSAGE=`git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s`
```

to retrieve the last commit message, and work from there to create your script. It's also possible to retrieve every commit message included in that push, by using:

```
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    MESSAGE=`git log -1 $newrev --pretty=format:%s`
    doSomethingElse...
done
```

As for copying it to somewhere else, you can use anything you'd use in other scripts, like scp, rsync... Just clone/update a local copy in a temp dir and sync it to your remote location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Will explore what you have said.

Comment: @MikashHaria :  hope it helped. Please remember to report back if it worked or not, so that other people reaching this post can benefit too